# Filtering out users that appear in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter out any user whose id appears in an array of strings. I am trying to use a filter() method to do this but strugglign with implementing the logic.

```
    const x = [
      {
        notebookId: "abc",
        notebookUsers: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      },
      {
        notebookId: "cde",
        notebookUsers: [2, "foo", 4, 3],
      },
      {
        notebookId: "fgh",
        notebookUsers: ["bla", 4, 5, "123"],
      },
      {
        notebookId: "qqq",
        notebookUsers: [33, 16, 12],
      },
      {
        notebookId: "ab",
        notebookUsers: ["abc", 23213, 2131, 33],
      },
    ];

    const y = ["abc", "123", "bla", "foo"];

    const filteredUsersArray = x.filter((nb) => {
      const filteredUsers = nb.notebookUsers.filter(
        (user) => !y.includes(user)
      );
      return (
        nb.notebookId !== "welcome" &&
        nb.notebookId !== "null" &&
        nb.notebookId !== "1234" &&
        filteredNotebookUsers.length > 0
      );
    });

    console.log(filteredUsersByNotebookArray);
```

Result:

```
[  
  {    
    notebookId: "abc",    
    notebookUsers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, "foo", 4, 3]
  },
  {
    notebookId: "cde",
    notebookUsers: [2, "foo", 4, 3]
  },
  {
    notebookId: "fgh",
    notebookUsers: ["bla", 4, 5, "123"]
  },
  {
    notebookId: "qqq",
    notebookUsers: [33, 16, 12, "abc", 23213, 2131, 33]
  },
  {
    notebookId: "ab",
    notebookUsers: ["abc", 23213, 2131, 33]
  }
]
```

This doesn't appear to remove the forbidden ids. Not sure where i am wrong.

Comment: without any data and result it's hard to get the error. please add some data and result.

Comment: Insufficient data, please provide the data for usersArray.

Comment: please add the result as well.

Comment: Okay I have added the result of logging ``filteredUsersArray`` out in my dev tools

Comment: why does the result get more data than in the original data?

Answer (score 1):

you are returning a check on a variable called `filteredNotebookUsers` which does not exist, update the return statement to check the length of the filteredUsers array

```js
const x = [
  {
    notebookId: "abc",
    notebookUsers: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  },
  {
    notebookId: "cde",
    notebookUsers: [2, "foo", 4, 3],
  },
  {
    notebookId: "fgh",
    notebookUsers: ["bla", 4, 5, "123"],
  },
  {
    notebookId: "qqq",
    notebookUsers: [33, 16, 12],
  },
  {
    notebookId: "ab",
    notebookUsers: ["abc", 23213, 2131, 33],
  },
];

const y = ["abc", "123", "bla", "foo"];

const filteredUsersArray = x.filter((nb) => {
  const filteredUsers = nb.notebookUsers.filter(
    (user) => !y.includes(user)
  );
  return (
    nb.notebookId !== "welcome" &&
    nb.notebookId !== "null" &&
    nb.notebookId !== "1234" &&
    filteredUsers.length > 0
  );
});

console.log(filteredUsersArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood what you are trying to achieve.
Maybe it is the following:

```
'Before' [
  {
    notebookId: 'abc',
    notebookUsers: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
  },
  {
    notebookId: 'cde',
    notebookUsers: [ 2, 'foo', 4, 3 ]
  },
  {
    notebookId: 'fgh',
    notebookUsers: [ 'bla', 4, 5, '123' ]
  },
  {
    notebookId: 'qqq',
    notebookUsers: [ 33, 16, 12 ]
  },
  {
    notebookId: 'ab',
    notebookUsers: [ 'abc', 23213, 2131, 33 ]
  }
]
'After' [
  {
    notebookId: 'abc',
    notebookUsers: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
  },
  { notebookId: 'cde', notebookUsers: [ 2, 4, 3 ] },
  { notebookId: 'fgh', notebookUsers: [ 4, 5 ] },
  {
    notebookId: 'qqq',
    notebookUsers: [ 33, 16, 12 ]
  },
  {
    notebookId: 'ab',
    notebookUsers: [ 23213, 2131, 33 ]
  }
]
```

Here is the code to return the same `Array` but without the `forbiddenIDs`

```
const forbiddenIDs = ["abc", "123", "bla", "foo"];
const filteredUsersArray = notebooksArray.map((nb) => {
const filteredUsers = nb.notebookUsers.filter(
    (user) => !forbiddenIDs.includes(user)
  );
  return (
    nb.notebookId !== "welcome" &&
    nb.notebookId !== "null" &&
    nb.notebookId !== "1234" &&
    filteredUsers.length > 0
  ) && { notebookId: nb.notebookId, notebookUsers: filteredUsers};
});
console.log(filteredUsersArray);
```

`.map` returns a new Array that will be stored in `filteredUsersArray`.
With `&& { notebookId: nb.notebookId, notebookUsers: filteredUsers};` we mean that if the previous condition is true we return an object like we had before but with the filtered users. So we add the same `notebookId` that we had before, and the `notebookUsers` array will now contain the filtered users.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `filter` doesn't do quite what you expect.
Consider this small example:

```js
const userIds = [1,2,3,4];
const filteredUserIds = userIds.filter(id => id >= 3);
console.log(userIds);         // [1,2,3,4]
console.log(filteredUserIds); // [3,4]
```

**`filter` does not change the array that it is filtering**

It looks like what you want to do is to `map` the notebooks so that the users are filtered, and then filter the mapped notebooks:

```js
    const filteredNotebooks =
      x.map((nb) => {
        const filteredUsers = nb.notebookUsers.filter(
          (user) => !y.includes(user)
        );
        return { ...nb, notebookUsers: filteredUsers };
      }).filter((nb) => {
        return (
          nb.notebookId !== "welcome" &&
          nb.notebookId !== "null" &&
          nb.notebookId !== "1234" &&
          nb.notebookUsers.length > 0
        );
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are wanting. But you can try in this way -

```js
const x = [
    {
      notebookId: "abc",
      notebookUsers: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    },
    {
      notebookId: "cde",
      notebookUsers: [2, "foo", 4, 3],
    },
    {
      notebookId: "fgh",
      notebookUsers: ["bla", 4, 5, "123"],
    },
    {
      notebookId: "qqq",
      notebookUsers: [33, 16, 12],
    },
    {
      notebookId: "ab",
      notebookUsers: ["abc", 23213, 2131, 33],
    },
  ];

  const y = ["abc", "123", "bla", "foo"];

  const filteredUsersArray = x.filter((nb) => {
    return nb.notebookUsers.filter(
      (user) => !y.includes(user)
    )
  });

  console.log(filteredUsersArray);
```